# reload multiple table cells with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have many forms in a page, each form with several inputs. When you click Submit on a form (say Form0), inputs are send to Reassign.php,that perform a search in a DB according to user inputs, and then a cell with div id="Cell0" in a table of the page is reloaded with data echoed by Reassign.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Form0").submit(function(){
        var MyVariables = $(this).serialize();
        $('#Cell00').load('Reassign.php?MyVariables=' + MyVariables);
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Form1").submit(function(){
        var MyVariables = $(this).serialize();
        $('#Cell10').load('Reassign.php?MyVariables=' + MyVariables);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

A stripped down version of the table:

```
<table>                
  <tr>
    <td><div id="Cell00"><img src="Image0.jpg"/></div></td>
    <td><div id="Cell01">Text1</div></td>
    <td><div id="Cell02">Price1</div></td>
    <td><div>
             <form name="Form0" id="Form0">
                <input type="hidden" name="Qst" value="0">
                <input type="image" src="ReloadRed.gif" alt="Submit"/>
                <select name="cmb1"><option>cmb1Option1</option><option>cmb1Option2</option></select>
                <select name="cmb2"><option>cmb2Option1</option><option>cmb2Option1</option></select>
             </form>
          </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="Cell10"><img src="Image0.jpg"/></div></td>
    <td><div id="Cell11">Text1</div></td>
    <td><div id="Cell12">Price1</div></td>
    <td><div>
             <form name="Form1" id="Form1">
                <input type="hidden" name="Qst" value="0">
                <input type="image" src="ReloadRed.gif" alt="Submit"/>
                <select name="cmb1"><option>cmb1Option1</option><option>cmb1Option2</option></select>
                <select name="cmb2"><option>cmb2Option1</option><option>cmb2Option1</option></select>
             </form>
          </div>
    </td>
  </tr>                      
</table>
```

A sample Reassign.php:

```
<?php
  session_start(); 
  $MyVariables = $_GET['MyVariables '];
  $cmb1 = $_GET['cmb1'];
  $cmb2 = $_GET['cmb2'];
  $cmb3 = $_GET['cmb3'];
  parse_str($MyVariables);
  $Preg=$MyVariables;

 $link = mysql_connect("localhost", usr, pswrd) or die(mysql_error());
 @mysql_select_db("MyDB") or die( "Unable to select database"); 
 mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = "SELECT Img FROM MyTable WHERE Column1=$cmb1 AND Column2=cmb2";
    if($success = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {    
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $image="../ImageFolder/".$row[0].".png";
       }
    }         
echo "<img src=\"".$image."\" />";
?>
```

This is OK.

Now I want other cells in the table to change as well, but with different (and related) data. Indeed, in the DB seach by Reassign.php, $row[0] is echoed (and thus loaded) in Cell00, and I want $row[1] to be send to Cell01, $row[2] to Cell02 and so on.
My problem is that right now I'm loading Cell0 echoing their content. I think i could do the job calling different php (Reassign0.php to echo data to Cell00, Reassign1.php to echo data to Cell01) but seems rather odd. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are doing here, can you provide more code ? (html & php) ? It seems like you could do it in a much more efficient way...

Comment: You should retrieve the data as JSON and then parse and place each cell's value appropriately. To do this you would need to use something other than `load()`, perhaps `post()` or `get()`.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with your php file, the way you appear to have organized your SQL table, with the way you're using jQuery, and even with the HTML. It appears you need to research more deeply how each of these is to be used. It's also possible that you just need more experience. The question is thus difficult to answer because it requires a complete re-think of many of the things you're doing to be fully correct.

Comment: @colepanike Yes, you're right. I'm a biologist, working as a biologist, and with little experience in this programming field. I've done quite good things thou. I'll re-think the logic of what I want to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: I feel ashamed. I should not have been so unkind in my tone. If you are just learning then you've done very well! I recommend that you bring in a detabase expert and a web developer as consultants on your project through. It will be worth it.

Comment: @colepanike don't worry, you were not rude. You just rightly pointed out general problems, which is usefull to learn and to think things more than twice. Almost done with Charleshaa solution, although I'm still learning about decoding json...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better approach... You can echo JSON instead of HTML from you PHP script, with all fields of the row. (Other code must be put in place for this to work for you, I'll let you research it on your own)

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

In your JS, get that json with `$.getJSON(url, callback)` or `$.get(url, callback)` depending on your server configuration

Then, loop through the cells and inject the data in your callback

```
$.getJSON('Reassign.php?MyVariables='+MyVariables, function(row){
  for(i=0;i<row.length;i++){
    $("#Cell0"+i).html(row[i]);
  }
});
```

EDIT: if you data is not already formatted as HTML (like for images), be sure to do it in your callback. For example, if the first element is always an image URL and the rest is plain data, you can do :

```
$.getJSON('Reassign.php?MyVariables='+MyVariables, function(row){
  for(i=0;i<row.length;i++){
    var content = ( i == 0 ) ? '<img src="'+row[i]+'" alt="" />' : row[i];
    $("#Cell0"+i).html(content);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'll try this. And think about the global logic, as I responded to colepanike. Thanks!

Comment: @user1726522 Good luck and be sure not to forget to accept an answer once it works for you